# Some Arqade subdomains do not work

Tags: bug, status-completed, domain-name

I would expect the various Stack Exchange subdomains to work with the new [arqade.com](http://arqade.com) domain. Is there a reason we are not forwarding [blog.arqade.com](http://blog.arqade.com) and [chat.arqade.com](http://chat.arqade.com), but are forwarding [meta.arqade.com](http://meta.arqade.com)?